# Magento 2 Call catalog_product_price.xml file for specific type product

Tags: magento2, product

I create one layout file catalog_product_prices.xml file and using this file bind one phtml file so, this phtml file calls every type of product like bundle, group, and simple.

My need is to call this PHTML file only for group and simple types of products not for bundle products.

When I tried to get product type on phtml file every time it's returned a child product like return simple product ID and type.

How to solve this problem ?

catalog_product_prices.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Magecomp_Tierprice::css/tierprice.css"/>
    </head>
    <referenceBlock name="render.product.prices">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="default" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="prices" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="tier_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Extension::product/price/tier_prices.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
     </layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the layout like this.

```
catalog_product_view_type_simple.xml -> Simple Product

catalog_product_view_type_virtual.xml -> Virtual Product

catalog_product_view_type_configurable.xml -> Configurable Product

catalog_product_view_type_downloadable.xml -> Downloadable Product

catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml -> Bundle Product

catalog_product_view_type_grouped.xml -> Grouped Product 

catalog_product_view_type_custom.xml -> Custom Product Type
```

Comment: But I want to render the template as per the above way and this thing did not apply to catalog_product_view_type_simple.xml or catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml file how to do this